# What is the best way to jump from one textbox to another using the Microsoft client-side AJAX Library?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to find a reusable way to set focus from one text box to another upon enter using ASP.NET, but using client-side JavaScript to do so.

The only reason I mention this is to be done in ASP.NET, is due to the fact that client Id's of the controls that ASP.NET renders can be different than what was specified in the markup.

Comment: Is there something you need to do server side with this? Otherwise it's probably pure java script and not ajax or asp.net at all.

Comment: Define "jump from one text box to another" - by that do you mean set the focus when the user presses the enter key in the first box?

Comment: Doesn't sound intuitive.Do you have other applications in the organization that follow this convention?

Comment: We are using bar code scanners that inject a carriage return when something is scanned in, and I want to set focus to the following textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified following code to get your goal.

```
    /***********************************************
    * Disable "Enter" key in Form script- By Nurul Fadilah(nurul@REMOVETHISvolmedia.com)
    * This notice must stay intact for use
    * Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code
    ***********************************************/

function handleEnter(field, event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < field.form.elements.length; i++)
                if (field == field.form.elements[i])
                break;
            i = (i + 1) % field.form.elements.length;
            field.form.elements[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: See my comment @Odge as TAB may be the better key to use, in which case you're just using enter as a tabindex replacement with this code. I'm assuming TAB won't work for BlueSam for some reason, so he may want to pass the id of the NEXT field rather than the current field in order to be explicit about navigation. Failing TAB and assuming these are plain single line text boxes, maybe down or up arrow? ENTER usually means "send my data" in data entry if you aren't in multi-line. Good catch on using enter inside a form and needing to redirect it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
function ChangeOnEnter (event, target) {
     if(event.keyCode === 13){
         document.getElementById(target).focus();
         return false;
     }
}

<input type="text" id="first" onKeyPress="ChangeOnEnter(event,'second')"/>
<input type="text" id="second"/>
```

Hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Deleted my post b/c it was redundant. The only thing I would recommend is not using ENTER... Assuming there's something that tabindex can't solve, I would still recommend using TAB as the "move to next" key as that is the UI convention. 
"Nice boring UIs for the adult in all of us" is the road to user friendly applications.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the tabindex html element property to allow users to  through the fields.  This is, in my opinion, a universal mechanism for moving through a form.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex